# Is this pseudo code or some programming language

Tags: programming-languages

I'm reading about graph traversal in this [PDF](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mehlhorn/ftp/Toolbox/GraphTraversal.pdf%20PDF) and see some unfamiliar symbols. Is this code sample just pseudocode or is it some language I haven't seen before? If pseudocode, does it have some formal schema that will let me look up the unfamiliar symbols?

Bitmap sample here:
[image]

Comment: You may find an existing discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111645/breadth-first-traversal-using-c-sharp where this algorithm is implemented in C# while the queue structure is introduced, and IMHO is much easier to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a formal mathematical style of pseudocode sometimes referred to as [**pidgin code**](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidgin_code). Very few real languages use symbols like that, but there are some, such as [APL](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29).

There is no "glossary of symbols" per se, because every author uses his or her own flavor, but they tend to follow commonly-understood math notation.

This particular piece of code on BFS is very widely quoted. [Wikipedia's BFS article](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) has an "ASCII" translation of it.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [pidgin code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidgin_code) - a mix of pseudocode and math notation.  For determining the meaning of the math notation, rapidtables has a [good reference for the symbols](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/symbols/Basic_Math_Symbols.htm).