# Get the full name of a nested property and its parents

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

How can I get the full name of a nested property by its parent using reflection in C#? I mean, for example we have this classes:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Grade Grade { get; set; }
}

public class Grade
{
    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public GradGroup GradGroup { get; set; }
}

public class GradGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

I have "GradGroup" and Student as method parameters and want "Grade.GradeGroup" as output:

```
public string GetFullPropertyName(Type baseType, string propertyName)
    {
        // how to implement that??
    }
```

Call the method:

```
GetFullPropertyName(typeof(Student), "GradeGroup"); // Output is Grade.GradeGroup
```

Comment: so you want fully qualified name ?

Comment: It seems to me that the only way that this could would is if the method signature was `IEnumerable<string> GetFullPropertyNames(Type, Type) - otherwise it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @PranayRana - The OP seems to be traversing the object model to find a nested property that matches the name provided. Nothing to do with a FQN.

Comment: @PranayRana I want ParentName + "." + PropertyName. But I don't know how many nested types are there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The property may not be unique as it might exist on several components so you should  return an `IEnumerable<string>`. That being said you can traverse the property tree using `GetProperties` of `Type`:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFullPropertyName(Type baseType, string propertyName)
{
    var prop = baseType.GetProperty(propertyName);
    if(prop != null)
    {
        return new[] { prop.Name };
    }
    else if(baseType.IsClass && baseType != typeof(string)) // Do not go into primitives (condition could be refined, this excludes all structs and strings)
    {
        return baseType
            .GetProperties()
            .SelectMany(p => GetFullPropertyName(p.PropertyType, propertyName), (p, v) => p.Name + "." + v);
    }
    return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
}
```

Comment: Why not go into primitives? What if I like to search for `Length`? Shouldn't it return all `String` properties? Or for `Tick`? Shouldn't all `DateTime` properties come back?

Comment: @Oliver yeah, that was my first go at it to, the problem is that there is no simple stop condition for the recursive call. `DateTime` has properties of type `DateTime` for example, and this would be infinitely recursive, other more indirect recursive relations are also possible within base types. You can probably come up with a better stop condition, but as far as the requirements in this question were concerned this was not necessary

Comment: Why when I use .ToList() or First() at the end of the method, it goes to the infinitely cycle?

Comment: @zmovahedi The methods assumes you don't have cycles in your data structure. We could add a hashset to keep track of visited types and not revisit them if you have cycles in your data model. what arguments are causing the issue ?

Comment: I need to loop over the method result to access its items, Otherwise, How can I access them?

Comment: @zmovahedi yes, the usage of `First()` or `ToList()` is fine. I was asking what parameters do you pass to `GetFullPropertyName` and does you data model have cycles, for example `class Student { Student Child { get;set ;} }`

Comment: I use exactly like this: `GetFullPropertyName(typeof(Student), "GradeGroup").ToList();` and my classes are the ones I mentioned above in the question. Without any changes.

Comment: This is the code I tested with, it works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hoCPiH

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: I didn't thought about *recursive Types* like `DateTime.Now` is of type `DateTime`. I just updated my answer to track all visited types to get out of the loop. This is still not perfect, but maybe I can improve it.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes, you're right. I was wrong somewhere. Sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Nice one. I would go for a generic approach though, GetFullPropertyName<T>(PropertyName)

Answer (score 3):

- Use reflection to find all properties of a type
- Use bread first search to find the nested property with given name
- Concatenate the property names you found in the path with a "."

Here are some useful references

- [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [System.Reflection.PropertyInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Breadth-first traversal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111645/breadth-first-traversal)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I was just too late, but that's the solution that I came up with:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetFullPropertyNames(this Type type, string propertyName)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyName));

        return GetFullPropertyNamesImpl(type, propertyName, new HashSet<Type>());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetFullPropertyNamesImpl(Type type, string propertyName, ICollection<Type> visitedTypes)
    {
        if (visitedTypes.Contains(type))
            yield break;

        visitedTypes.Add(type);

        var matchingProperty = type.GetProperty(propertyName);

        if (matchingProperty != null)
        {
            yield return matchingProperty.Name;
        }

        foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            var matches = GetFullPropertyNamesImpl(property.PropertyType, propertyName, visitedTypes);

            foreach (var match in matches)
            {
                yield return $"{property.Name}.{match}";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By using this class example:

```
public class GrandChild
{
    public int IntegerValue { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    public bool BooleanValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeValue { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public GrandChild First { get; set; }
    public GrandChild Second { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public Child Mother { get; set; }
    public Child Father { get; set; }

}
```

You would call it

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var matches = typeof(Parent).GetFullPropertyNames("Ticks");

        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

And the output would be:

> Mother.First.DateTimeValue.Ticks
>
> Mother.First.DateTimeValue.TimeOfDay.Ticks