# Water Jug Puzzle with N Jug

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm trying to solve the famous "water jug puzzle" (like in the movie *Die Hard with a Vengeance*).

I solve easily the puzzle with supports of 2 jugs in C#.

But now I would like to achieve the same with N number of jugs (2, 3, 4, 5, ...). It completely changes the way the algorithm works.

My current solution works on the following principle :

1. Fill the m litre jug and empty it into n liter jug.
2. Whenever the m liter jug becomes empty fill it.
3. Whenever the n liter jug becomes full empty it.
4. Repeat steps 1,2,3 till either n liter jug or the m liter jug contains d litres of water.

Then, I repeat the operation by reversing the order of the jugs and I take the fastest solution between the two.

This system works great with 2 jugs but cannot work with more jugs.

Reminder of the rules: You have N jugs of water, each with a specific capacity. It is possible to fill a jug completely from a faucet, empty a jug completely into a sink, and transfer the contents of one jug to another (subject to available capacity of target and current fill of source).

The goal is to get ONE jug with a given amount of water (the goal) and find the fastest way to do it.

For example: Two jugs of 3 and 5 liters represented as an array of int [3, 5]. The goal is to have a jug with 4 (represented by an int). The function takes these two elements as parameters and displays the fastest path (if there is one).

The way to get there is (in 6 steps in this case):
(0,5)
(3,2)
(0,2)
(2,0)
(2,5)
(3,4)

As explained before, I solved this simple version with 2 jugs easily.
But how to do it with N jugs? Has anyone ever done something similar? Or have an idea?

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged C#, as you're asking about an algorithm which can be any language.

Comment: If `n` and capacities are small, breadth-first search works well.

Comment: Are you familiar with dynamic programming? If so, a subproblem is defined by the levels in the jugs. With jugs of size 3 and 5, there are exactly `4*6 = 24` subproblems. In general, the number of subproblems is the product of the sizes plus 1.

Comment: Here is [the relevant movie clip](https://youtu.be/2vdF6NASMiE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only precise operations are

1. ***FILL***: Completely fill any jug from an infinite water supply.
2. ***EMPTY***: Completely empty the contents of any jug.
3. ***POUR***: Pour the contents of jug **A** into jug **B** until jug **B** is full or jug **A** is empty.

These operations perform, respectively:

1. `amount[A] = capacity[A];`
2. `amount[A] = 0;`
3. `temp = min(available(B), amount[A]); amount[B] += temp; amount[A] -= temp;`

With this special convenience function:
`available(i) => capacity[i] - amount[i]`

Perform a [breadth first search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111645/breadth-first-traversal) from among these relatively few available operations until the desired amount of water exists in one of the jugs.

There are N choices of indices for operation 1 and 2 (FILL or EMPTY), and there are (N * N-1) choices for operation 3 (POUR), in other words choose a random A and a random B that is not equal to A.

#### Optimization Note

A useful optimization is to prevent enqueuing search states that have already been deemed reachable with fewer steps.  A *state* here is at first glance represented by the values in the *amount* array, but can also be represented by the number of jugs of each unique capacity and amount, because the jugs themselves are not unique except for their capacity and current amount.